# How to set the color for each component in the graph itself, which was created using the svg-graph gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, graph, colors, rubygems

Good afternoon! I need to plot user activity graphs in svg format using the [svg-graph](https://github.com/lumean/svg-graph2) gem. No one can tell you how you can change the color of, say, a line or column of a graph? Because after a certain number, the color is always determined by one - black.

I have been working with this gem not so long ago, so I will be grateful for any help)

```
require 'SVG/Graph/Bar'

x_axis = ['1-10', '10-30', '30-50', '50-70', 'older']

options = {
  :width             => 640,
  :height            => 300,
  :stack             => :side,  # the stack option is valid for Bar graphs only
  :fields            => x_axis,
  :graph_title       => "kg per head and year chocolate consumption",
  :show_graph_title  => true,
  :show_x_title      => true,
  :x_title           => 'Age in years',
  :show_y_title      => true,
  :y_title           => 'kg/year',
  :y_title_location  => :end,
  :no_css            => true
}

male_data   = [2, 4, 6, 4, 2]
female_data = [1, 5, 4, 5, 2.7]

g = SVG::Graph::Bar.new(options)

g.add_data( {
    :data => female_data,
    :title => "Female"
  })
g.add_data( {
    :data => male_data,
    :title => "Male"
  })

# graph.burn            # this returns a full valid xml document containing the graph
# graph.burn_svg_only   # this only returns the <svg>...</svg> node
File.open('bar.svg', 'w') {|f| f.write(g.burn_svg_only)}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my question :( https://github.com/lumean/svg-graph2/issues/20

Comment: Although you can add a line of code with your hands to set the color to the required fragment after the graph is formed - `.key#item_number#,.fill#item_number#{ fill-opacity: 0.7; fill: #6699FF; stroke: none; stroke-width: 1px; }` before `.keyText`